# Can we able to upload lower version name in play store

Tags: android

In my project we have two build, First build (version name 1.0.13, with version code 12),This is already uploaded in beta version.Now I want to upload second build(version name 1.1.1 with version code 13).

Question is If I want to upload first build changes with (version 1.0.14 with version code as 14). Can I able to upload with lower version name in playstore in beta version

Comment: Sure you can. You just need to have a new version code, the version number can differ.

Answer (score 0):

Please rephrase your question because your request is unclear to me. However, if you would like to know if you can update the app to a new code version, but keep the app in Beta - yes, you can do that.